# Different arrows at two port and adder in CircuiTikZ

Tags: circuitikz

the following circuitikz snippet

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[below]{$x(t)$} to[amp, >] (4,0);
        \draw (5,0) node[adder](adder){};
        \draw (4,0) to[short, i=$$] (adder.west);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: got]

how do I get the arrow left to the adder closer to the adder as with the amp?

Using the standard tikz arrow

```
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[below]{$x(t)$} to[amp, >] (4,0);
        \draw (5,0) node[adder](adder){};
        \draw[->] (4,0) -- (adder.west);
    \end{circuitikz}
```

is at the correct position but has the wrong arrow shape.

[image: got2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is using the `anchor=...` option to position (any) node along your path.

For example:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node[below]{$x(t)$} to[amp, >] (4,0)
            node[adder, anchor=west](adder){};
        \node [inputarrow, anchor=tip] at (adder.west) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Notice that `standalone` expects a `tikzpicture`, and it needs additional arguments to "wrap" correctly a `circuitikz`. But given that a `circuitikz` is exactly the same as a `tikzpicture`, I choose the easy way out.)